# Sending data from ASP.net to Python and send it again to ASP.net

Tags: python, asp.net, integration

So, I'm working on an assignment that requires me to make an image classification on Python. If users want to interact with my image classification program, they can upload their image through asp.net to python, and the classification result needs to be thrown back to asp.net so that users can see.
My question is about how to send data from asp.net to python and so the otherwise... I know nothing about integration, I don't even know where to begin with, can anyone help me, please? :(

Comment: Try [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)

Comment: SO doesn't encourage 'How to' type questions. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @HaBom okay, thanks for telling! c: